# PHP strpos check mail on @ and

Tags: php, function, strpos

I made a little PHP script that checks if an email is valid.
The only problem is that it doesn't check if the dot is BEHIND the '@'. It accept emails like this: Hi.Hello@hotmailcom when it should only accept emails like HiHello@hotmail.com

This is my script:

```
<?php
$mail = $_POST['mail'];

    function checkmail($mail)
        {
            if ((strpos ($mail, '@') !== false) && (strpos ($mail, ".") !==false))
            {                   
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

if(checkmail($mail))    
{
echo"Goed"; 
}   
else    
{       
echo"Fout";     
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`...

Comment: I like how you call your script "he".

Comment: @Juhana The joy of gender based grammar... :o)

Comment: Haha I just noticed, I'm Dutch so I think the problem lies there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't badly reinvent the wheel, use `filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`, or in your case better `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mail', 
FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`.

http://php.net/filter_var
http://php.net/filter_input

Answer (score 1):

As said in the above posts, you can use `filter_var` PHP function, BUT only if your PHP version is greater than **5.2.0**.
If you want some more generic email validation, you can also use regular expressions, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses) and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (
(strpos ($mail, '@') !== false) && 
(strpos ($mail, '@') == strrchr($mail, '@')) && 
(strripos($mail, ".") > strpos ($mail, '@'))
)
{return true;}

// explication:
//
// (strpos ($mail, '@') !== false) => '@' character is in the string
// (strpos ($mail, '@') == strrchr($mail, '@')) => '@' character is unique
// (strripos($mail, ".") > strpos ($mail, '@')) => last position of '.' character is      
// greater than '@' character position
```

Comment: <?php
$mail = $_POST['mail'];

    function checkmail($mail)
        {
            if (filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            {                   
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

if(checkmail($mail))    
{
echo"Goed"; 
}   
else    
{       
echo"Fout";     
}

?>